# TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

Please help me solve the error. I have attached my index.js code routes.js code and db.js code and the error description.
I've been trying hard to solve the error.

> index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routes = require('./routes');
const path = require('path');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const session = require('express-session');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const {
  con,
  sessionStore
} = require('./config/db');
const fs = require('fs');

require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));


//static files 
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css' , express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('/imgs' , express.static(__dirname + 'public/imgs'))

var sess = {
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }
  
  app.use(session(sess));
  app.use(fileUpload());
//set views
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

//
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
    res.render('index22')
})
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
   });

   let s;

const loginRequired = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.username) {
    s = req.session;
    next();
    } else {
    res.redirect('/auth/login');
    }
}
// app.get('/new', (req, res) => {
//   res.render('new');
//  });

//  app.get('/show', (req, res) => {
//   res.render('show');
//  });

// app.get('/', loginRequired, (req, res) => {
//     res.redirect('/new');
// });
// app.get('/', loginRequired, (req, res) => {
//   res.redirect('/show');
// });

 
app.get('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);//call for main index page
app.post('/new', loginRequired, routes.new);//call for signup post 
app.get('/show', loginRequired, routes.show);







app.use('/auth', auth);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on http://${process.env.HOST}:${port}`));
```

> routes.js

```
const {
   con,
   sessionStore
 } = require('./config/db');
exports.new = function(req, res){
    message = '';
   if(req.method == "POST"){
      const post  = req.body;
      const username= post.username;
      const title= post.title;
      const state= post.state;
      const category= post.category;
      const description= post.description;
 
      if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
        const file = req.files.uploads;
        const img_name=file.name;
 
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('public/imgs/uploads/'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
                  if (err)
 
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                        const sql = "INSERT INTO `nt_data`(`username`,`title`,`state`,`category`, `img_name` ,`description`) VALUES ('" + username + "','" + title + "','" + state + "','" + category + "','" + image + "','" + description + "')";
 
                            const query = con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                                 res.redirect('show/'+result.insertUsername);
                            });
                       });
          } else {
            message = "This format is not allowed , please upload file with '.png','.gif','.jpg'";
            res.render('new.ejs',{message: message});
          }
   } else {
      res.render('new');
   }
 
};

exports.show = function(req, res){
    const message = '';
    const username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

> db.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env') });

// config for your database
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT)
});

var sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}/* session store options */, con);

// connect to your database
con.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to database");
});

module.exports = { con, sessionStore };
```

> Description of the error:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Internship\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\routes.js:50:12)
    at Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:133:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Nt\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
```

I guess mainly the error is in the routes.js file
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Just update `const` to `let` in the `show` function:

```
exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    const username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

Or given you don't really need to reassign it, just create the variable inside the body if the `if` statement:

```
exports.show = function(req, res){
    const username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      const message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 5):

Once you declare a `const` you cannot reassign it. Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for more information.

This won't work

```
const message = ""
message = "show not found!";
```

This will

```
let message = ""
message = "show not found!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `connect-mongo`. Double-check with the `express-mysql-session` latest docs and check if you're importing packages you already required accidentally. Sometimes, ``IDEs like `Visual Studio Code` does this. It was importing `const{express-session}` by the IDE and assigning it to mongostore.

Answer (score 0):

The "Assignment to constant variable" error occurs when attempting to modify or redeclare a variable declared using the const keyword. In JavaScript, variables declared with const are read-only and cannot be reassigned a new value after initialization. This behavior ensures that the variable remains constant throughout its scope. To fix this error, consider using the let keyword instead of const if you need to update the variable's value. Alternatively, ensure that you are not attempting to reassign the constant variable inadvertently. Remember, const is appropriate for values that remain constant during execution, while let is more suitable for mutable variables.

as an example I am giving an code.

```
  const pi = 3.14; // This variable cannot be reassigned a new value

// To fix the error, use 'let' if you need to change the value
let counter = 0;
counter = 1; 
// This is valid with 'let', but not with 'const'
```

Using let instead of const allows you to modify the variable's value when needed, avoiding the "Assignment to constant variable" error.

So I try try to find out where the error is !

updating const to let or var in the router.js file  solve the problem. here is the updated code.

```
exports.show = function(req, res){
    let message = '';
    const username = req.params.username;
    const sql="SELECT * FROM `nt_data` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'"; 
    con.query(sql, function(err, result){
      if(result.length <= 0)
      message = "show not found!";
      
      res.render('show.ejs',{data:result, message: message});
   });
};
```